# How i can get one seekbar listener for any item with Android?

Tags: android, dialog, seekbar

Hi i'm trying to change the values of any item of the list when the seekbar is changed but with this code only chenge the last item of the list when i move any seekbar. Do you have any idea?

this is the itemDialog adapter code
`

```
public class itemDialogadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Nota> {
    private TextView nota;
    private ArrayList<Nota> X;
    private int pos;
    private  Nota item;

    public itemDialogadapter(Context context, int layout_resource, ArrayList<Nota> data) {

        //Cridar al constructor del ArrayAdapter<item> amb super.
        super(context, layout_resource, R.id.especula_nota, data); // R.id.tipus
        X = data;

    }

    //SobreEscribim el contructor per defecte.
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); //Reaprofitem el que ja teniem
        pos = position;
        item = getItem(position); //Retorna l'Item que estaba a la posicio "position"

        //Obtenir referencies a les parts de l'item de la llista
        //a la posició "position"
        TextView Activitat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nom_tasca); // Busca dins de la pastilleta
        nota = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.especula_nota);

        //Ara  canviem les dades (com si marquem el checkbox,,,,)
        //Transferim dades del item al view que sortirà a la llista.
        nota.setText(String.format("%.3f", 0.000));
        Activitat.setText(String.format("%s %d %%:", item.getNomActivitat(), (int) item.getPercent()));

            SeekBar seekbar1 = (SeekBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
            seekbar1.setMax(10);
            seekbar1.setProgress(0);
            seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    //add here your implementation

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    //add here your implementation
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                              boolean fromUser) {
                    canvia_valor(progress,pos);
                }
            });




        return convertView;

    }

    public void canvia_valor(int progres, int pos) {
        nota.setText(String.format("%d", progres));

    }
}
```

Layout

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="bottom">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="nom_tipus+%"
        android:id="@+id/nom_tasca"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="mostra_nota"
            android:id="@+id/especula_nota"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nom_tipus"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nom_tipus" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[If you clic you can see the first seekbar has been moved and the value changes in the second item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Vj0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually problem is with method:

```
public void canvia_valor(int progres, int pos) {
    nota.setText(String.format("%d", progres));

}
```

Which is out side the scope of getView(). Thus always store last row value for nota(TextView).

Try to remove variable:
   `private  TextView nota;`
from global scope an declare inside getView().

Comment: I delete the function canvia_valor and i put the setText inside getView but dont works
 `
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                              boolean fromUser) {
                    nota.setText(String.format("%d", progress));
                }`